# XNA Moddable Game - Architecture Design and Reflection

Tags: c#, xna, architecture, modding

I've decided to embark on an XNA moddable game project of a simple rogue style. For all purposes of this question, I'm going to not be using a scripting engine, but rather allow modders to directly compile assemblies that are loaded by the game at run time. I know about the security problems this may raise.

So in order to expose the moddable content, I have gone about creating a generic project in XNA called `MyModel`. This contains a number of interfaces that all inherit from `IPlugin`, such as `IGameSystem`, `IRenderingSystem`, `IHud`, `IInputSystem` etc.

Then I've created another project called `MyRogueModel`. This references `MyModel` project, and holds interfaces such as `IMonster`, `IPlayer`, `IDungeonGenerator`, `IInventorySystem`. More rogue specific interfaces, but again, all interfaces in this project inherit from `IPlugin`.

Then finally, I've created *another* project called `MyRogueGame`, that references both `MyModel` and `MyRogueModel` projects. This project will be the game that you run and play. Here I have put the actual implementation of the `Monster`, `DungeonGenerator`, `InputSystem` and `RenderingSystem` classes. This project will also scan the mods directory during run time and load any `IPlugin`s it finds using reflection and override anything it finds from the default. For example if it finds a new implementation of the `DungeonGenerator` it will use that one instead.

Now my question is, in order to get this far, I have effectively 2 projects that contain nothing but interfaces... which seems a little... strange ? For people to create mods for the game, I would give them both the `MyModel` and `MyRogueModel` assemblies in which they would reference. I'm not sure whether this is the right way to do it, but my reasoning goes as follows :

If I write 1 input system, I can use it in any game I write.

If I create 3 rogue like games, and a modder writes 1 rendering system, that modder could use the rendering system for all *3* games, because it all comes from the `MyModel` project.

I come from a more web based C# role, so having empty interface projects doesn't *seem* wrong, its just something I haven't done before. Before I embark on something that might be crazy, I'd just like to know whether this is a foolish idea and whether there's a better (or established) design principle I should be following ?

Comment: Seems good. In my experience, if you have a ton of Interfaces and you're doing C# or Java, then you're Doing It Right.

Comment: Cool, would it be seen as ok that abstract classes can make up part of these base projects too (`MyModel`), rather than just having them consist of interfaces ?

Comment: The difference between abstract classes and interfaces is that abstract classes define some behaviour. Interfaces define, well, interfaces. If `MyModel` defines some sort of behaviour expected of all subclasses by default, it ought to be an abstract class. [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html) might help you decide what's right.

Comment: Yes, I'm using abstract classes to have some very basic implementation of, say, the `IInputSystem`. I was just wondering whether mixing interfaces together with abstract classes was the done thing. I don't want to have to get all the modders of certain systems to have to write the same basic code. I can't mark a comment as an answer, but if you'll like to put one in, I'll mark it.

Comment: You're likely doing everything right then! By the way, the [Code Review Beta site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for getting feedback on code structure.

Comment: I made a [summary](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/45618/7804).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>This is a summary of the question comments.</sup>

Your solution is good.

It's completely fine to mix abstract classes and interfaces. They have distinct purposes: **Abstract classes** define behaviour expected of its subclasses. **Interfaces** define no behaviour, but only an interface to it. [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html) goes into more depth.

(By the way, the [Code Review beta site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is likely better for code structure questions.)